# AngularJS select2 not showing any values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using select2 the way it is specified in https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

```
<div ng-controller="sampleController>
    <select ui-select2 ng-model="select2" data-placeholder="Pick a number">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option ng-repeat="number in range" value="{{number.value}}">{{number.text}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

But this is not working for me. I see the dropdown but there are no values to select.

If I change it to have static list as follow then it works fine.

```
<div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <select ui-select2 ng-model="select2" data-placeholder="Pick a number">
        <option value="">value1</option>
        <option value="">value2</option>
        <option value="">value3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

My model is as follow

```
function sampleController($scope){
    $scope.select2="";
    $scope.range=[{text:"name1", value:"id1"},
        {text:"name2", value:"id2"},
        {text:"name3", value:"id3"}];

    $("#e1").select2();
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown looks fine to me. Can you include the model where you have `$scope.range`? Also, did you include `ng-controller` correctly?

Comment: Can you please check if my answer helps you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use $timeout like this :

```
function sampleController($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.select2="";
    $scope.range=[{text:"name1", value:"id1"},
        {text:"name2", value:"id2"},
        {text:"name3", value:"id3"}];
    $timeout(function(){
      $("#e1").select2();
    }, 0);
}
```

Why? Because $timeout will wait the end of the $digest (in your case ng-repeat) before to execute the function.

Your previous code did this :

- Render HTML
- $("#e1").select2();
- interpretate ng-repeat

So, your select2 function is executed before that your select has its option elements.

Look the $timeout documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout